# How does a web application work as mobile application?

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, offlineapps

This maybe a basic question, but I really wanted to ask it.
Consider a web application which is deployed on a cloud server and I want it to be available offline on a mobile(android device). Is it possible? Or will there be a separate installation on every mobile? How does phone gap or cordova help achieve it?

Comment: It would be possible to download the html and save it locally on the phone. Then when the user is offline you can show the local html instead of getting it from the cloud. This requires the user to be online atleast once though. And you should also ask yourself what the app would do if it is a web app that works in an offline mode.

Comment: Syncing is really hard, I have a project for just this problem... https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Cordova is an android application that has a webview (like a browser) for you to display an html app which is normally build with html+javascript. But cordova/phonegap applications should be made simpler than usual web application since smartphones has limited resources, unlike normal servers. There will be separate installation per mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Phone Gap, Cordova etc. build native application, each user must install it to work offline. You can also build such native application manually by yourself with [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). It can be easy to build but may require to changes in business logic to separate handle offline case, like store data locally and then sync when go online - this depend of application.